# jquery mouseenter / mousleave IE 10 issues

Tags: jquery, navigation, internet-explorer-10, mouseenter, mouseleave

I used jquerys mouseenter / mousleave to create a navigation. Works fine under all Browsers except of IE 10.

```
  $(".menu-item a").on("mouseenter", function() {
    "use strict";
      $(this).next(".menu-adds").children().addClass("active");
      $(".current_page_item").children(".menu-adds").children().removeClass("active");
  });


  $(".menu-item a").on("mouseleave", function() {
    "use strict";
      $(this).next(".menu-adds").children().removeClass("active");
      $(".current_page_item").children(".menu-adds").children().addClass("active");
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8omouec/2/

Howerver in IE10 the text and the image overlap when you hover over the navigation items.

Did not find a solution, but it seems not to be a problem with my css.

Comment: Why don't use css for this ?

Comment: This is just an excerpt, on mouseenter many things have to fire in the whole version. So I did it this way. Thanks for your suggestion, but I want to try it with javascript/jquery. And Im also interested in the IE10 issue. I cant imagin where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

For a temporary solution I set the transition with Mediaquery for ie10+ to none. This didnt solved the problem, but its a nice solution for me. Perhaps somebody else is interessted in this agreement.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    span.menu-image.active,
    span.menu-description.active {
            transition: none;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8omouec/4/